# How do I delete a set of records in Entity Framework .Core?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an EF model (and corresponding MSSQL table) "HCF".

I have another EF model (and MSSQL table), "HCFNotes".  There's no foreign key constraint or ManyToOne: they're just two separate tables.

I have an ASP.Net Core Razor page that deletes the HCF record like this:

```
var HCF = await _context.HCF.FindAsync(id);
_context.HCF.Remove(HCF);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I can get a list of the "associated notes" with this LINQ:

```
IQueryable<HCReportingNote> notesQuery =
    from n in _context.HCReportingNotes 
    where n.HCFId == HCF.ID
    select n;
```

I can delete all the associated notes in raw SQL like this:

```
delete from HCReportingNotes where ID = HCFId
```

But I'd prefer to use LINQ.

Q: What's the "correct" syntax to `.Select()` the list and `.Remove()` or `.Clear()` the associated notes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have already gotten the list of associated notes, then use `RemoveRange` on the `DbSet`, removing each element. Save changes can be applied after.

```
//...

var HCF = await _context.HCF.FindAsync(id);
_context.HCF.Remove(HCF);

IQueryable<HCReportingNote> notesQuery =
    from n in _context.HCReportingNotes 
    where n.HCFId == HCF.ID
    select n;

 _context.HCReportingNotes.RemoveRange(notesQuery);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

//...
```

Comment: `_context.HCReportingNotes.RemoveRange(notesQuery);`: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to delete larger amounts of elements, I would highly recommend this free nuget package that does such things without loading entities into memory: https://entityframework-plus.net/

With the accepted answer every element will be loaded into memory that needs to be deleted.

*Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the nuget package. They do offer a paid version that does even more stuff.*

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  In this case, the #/associated records is small (probably only one or two; seldom more than 10) and the records themselves are tiny.  So it's not an issue, either from a "memory" or a "performance" standpoint.